# Forgot in this sentence: Transitive or Intransitive?

Tags: grammar, objects, transitive-verbs, intransitive-verbs

"Today is Friday, but Adae forgot."

Hi everyone, so I encountered this sentence in a writing book . I believe "forgot" in this context is intransitive since there is no object in the second independent clause. If I were to re-write this, would it technically mean the same as :

"Today is Friday, but Adae forgot about it."?

Does anyone disagree that "forgot" is intransitive here? I can't really find anything in the dictionary to help me because all I see is forgot + "about" or "to" which would be intransitive.
https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/forget

Comment: You could as well imagine:  *Today is Friday, but Adae forgot [that it was Friday].* Then you would have a transitive-verb interpretation of *forgot*. Your best bet, though, is to interpret *forgot about* as an idiomatic, "prepositional verb." This type of verb takes an object. Put another way, *forgot about* is a transitive verb.

Comment: It's a bit like the old joke based on the French Foreign Legion _"I joined the Legion to forget". "Forget what?" "I don't know, I've forgotten"._  But in this case we know what Adea's forgotten, it's the fact that it's Friday, and that makes 'forgot' transitive, I think.

Comment: "Today is Friday, [but Adae forgot about it]" is clearly intransitive since the preposition "about" blocks any possibility of there being an object. "It" is complement of "about", and "about it" is complement of "forget".

Comment: You can call it transitive (with an understood object), or  you can call it intransitive, as you please, and as you understand the term_transitive_. Transitivity is not something you can always determine by examining the sentence, no matter how closely.

Comment: Understood objects don't count. There has to be an explicit NP object for the verb to be classified as transitive. The only exception is the so-called 'hollow clause', a non-finite clause with a missing non-subject element such as an object deriving its interpretation from an explicit antecedent. For example, in "The house will be ready for you to inspect in a few days", the missing object of "inspect" is recoverable from the subject of the clause, i.e. "the house".